# Prolog - How to replace elements in a list with other elements from another list

Tags: list, prolog

I'm new to Prolog and i'm having a trouble working with lists.
I'm have two lists with the same length, one complete and other incomplete.
Each list consists of pairs with this form `(Shape, Color)`
So first i have to define the Complete List:

```
CompleteList([(Square,Blue),(Circle,Red),(Triangle, Green),(Circle,Blue)]).
```

The second list (incomplete) is given. Something like:

```
IncompleteList = [(Square,Blue),_ , (Circle,_) , _ ].
```

Then I have this functor 'check', that as to detect the incomplete pairs like `(Circle,_)` and the empty spaces `_` , and replace with the element from the complete list. 
  The list in the end must have the same elements, the order does not matter, but the original pieces from the Incomplete List have to remain in the same place.
    So:

```
check(IncompleteList, CompleteList).
```

makes `IncompleteList` go from this:

```
IncompleteList = [(Square,Blue),_ , (Circle,_) , _ ].
```

to this:

```
IncompleteList = [(Square,Blue),(Triangle, Green),(Circle,Blue),(Circle,Red)].
```

or

```
IncompleteList = [(Square,Blue),(Circle,Blue),(Circle,Red),(Triangle, Green)].
```

...

For this example the length of the list is 4 but actually I'm working with list with length of 9, but I think it's no relevant since what I'm trying to know is how do I, first, detect the incomplete pairs, replace that pairs, and them put the other pieces randomly on the list.

Comment: Start with simpler examples: See "Art of Prolog"`. Then, say integers and so forth. Every extra step makes things much more complex for a beginner.`

Comment: Are you aware that names that start with a capital letter are variables? This problem has appeared in one form or other at least 3 times within the last week or so on StackOverflow, so I suppose this is some kind of homework assignment? Maybe you could show an attempt at what you've tried to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you'll come to appreciate Prolog declarative power showing you a simple solution, based on [select](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=select/3)/3:

```
equalize([], []).
equalize(A, B) :-
    select(X, A, A1),
    select(X, B, B1),
    equalize(A1, B1).
```

example:

```
?- Incomplete = [('Square','Blue'),_,('Circle',_),_], equalize([('Square','Blue'),('Circle','Red'),('Triangle','Green'),('Circle','Blue')], Incomplete).
Incomplete = [ ('Square', 'Blue'), ('Circle', 'Red'), ('Circle', 'Blue'), ('Triangle', 'Green')] ;
Incomplete = [ ('Square', 'Blue'), ('Circle', 'Red'), ('Circle', 'Blue'), ('Triangle', 'Green')] ;
...
```

you probably will gain a better understanding of the language if you try to remove duplicate solutions.

Comment: Well, Prolog is a little confusing for me, but i used the predicate select/3, i made it like this: `select([P | R], P, R). 
select([P | R], E, [ P | S]) :- select(R, E, S). 

permutation([], []). 

permutation(L, [P | R]) :- select(L, P, L1), 
      perm(L1, R).
` 
Permutation receives the 2 list.

Comment: your select/3 seems wrong... the list goes at second argument position. And what's the necessity of permutation/2 ? btw both are part of de facto standard Prolog library